# iOS Sharing Action Sheet - iPad Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, action

I have this `share` button that brings up the Share Menu from the bottom of the screen.

This is the code I use:

```
-(IBAction)ShareButton:(id)sender {
    NSString *texttoshare = @"My Text"; 
    UIImage *imagetoshare = _MyImage;
    NSArray *activityItems = @[texttoshare, imagetoshare];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint];

   [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

It works great ton iPhones, but crashes on iPads.

How can I implement the correct ViewControllers for iPads?

I'm guess something can be added inside this:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    //add alternative for iPad
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do that following thing:

Put this code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareButton;
shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(share:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
```

Then Create an action of it.

```
-(void)share:(id)sender {

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[chart getImage]];
NSArray *activityItems = @[image];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewControntroller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

activityViewControntroller.excludedActivityTypes = @[];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    activityViewControntroller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
    activityViewControntroller.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/4, 0, 0);

}

[self presentViewController:activityViewControntroller animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Hope It will works..